# How can I create a space in IBM Cloud?

Tags: ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I want to try the IBM speech to text API. I created an IBM cloud account and went to https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/speech-to-text. I see the error message:

> Please create a space in the selected org or choose another org.

Where can I create such a space? I wasn't able to find it yet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Watson doesn't allow some accounts to access some regions. Just choose another region, like "US South", when creating the resource, and the problem will be gone.